# hubConnection.Start taking really long

Tags: c#, signalr

I want to use SignalR in a WindowsService and have clients on other machines as Console/WPF Apps. So SignalR is Selfhosted/OWIN.

It is working perfectly with Client at localhost. If I try to connect over IP address or DNS-Name the connection needs 4 minutes to get  connected.

There is a problem with hubConnection.Start not returning for 4 minutes. I turned tracing on already. Here is a screenshot of the tracing:

[image: Client Connecting Trace]

As you can see it takes 4 min. I have the same Problem in Release Build Configuration and I run VS2015 as administrator on a Win 7 Pro x64 machine, Firewall turned off.

I can reproduce the problem with this example solution http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/804770/Implementing-SignalR-in-Desktop-Applications and just change the clients connection URL from localhost to the IP address. Different ports have the same  behaviour

After the long 4min connection time everything is working good without long delays. I already tried it with SignalR 2.0.3, 2.1.1 and 2.2.1.

I also embedded the SignalR 2.1.1 SourceCode and analysed the issue in the SignalR.Client sources.

At this line the debugger does not return for the 4 minutes:

```
            return Task.Factory.FromAsync<HttpWebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, ar => (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(ar), null);
```

in Method public static Task GetHttpResponseAsync(this HttpWebRequest request) in HttpHelper.cs

Update:
As Pawel suggested in comments I tried Fiddler to analyse the problem.
There were no entries for the server or the client. This didn't change after the 4minutes. The working communication after the 4 minutes is also invisible to Fiddler. Maybe because it fallback to localhost connection and this can't be seen by Fiddler?

But the really strange thing is, if I start the client as normal user instead of Administrator the client gets successfully connected (fast) and in Fiddler everything looks fine and I can see the communication happening there too.

Somehow this is working now. But I would really like to know what is wrong starting the client as Administrator?

Comment: This is weird since the connection timeout is like 10-15 seconds so it seems that the delay happens before signalR starts really connecting (e.g. maybe when it is trying to resolve the name?). Try fiddler or  network monitor to see how much time it takes SignalR to send the first HTTP request (which is negotiate). Or maybe the server needs 4 minutes to boot when it receives the first request?

Comment: @Pawel Thank you! I tried Fiddler and updated the question what I found out.